# How to submit a form with file uploads with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a long multistep form. which have text inputs and an upload file option. I'm trying to submit it to PHP with Ajax. I have tried `FormData` but I'm not sure how to send other select and text input fields.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

How can I do this?

```css
const addListingForm = $('#add-listing-form');

addListingForm.on('submit', function (e) {
  console.log('Submitted');

  const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('add-listing-form'));

  $.ajax({
    url: `${SITE_URL}/private/shared/process`,
    type: 'post',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (resp) {
      console.log(resp);
    },
    error: function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    },
  });

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="add-listing-form">
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="custom-input" />
  <input type="text" name="tagline" id="tagline" class="custom-input" />

  <input type="file" name="halal-certificate" class="custom-file-input" id="halal-certificate">

  <input type="file" name="list-photos[]" multiple class="custom-file-input" id="list-photos">

  <button type="submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224815/discussion-on-question-by-xotam-how-to-submit-a-form-with-file-uploads-with-ajax).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let title = document.getElementById("title").value;
let firstFile= document.getElementById("list-photos[]").files[0];
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append("file1", firstFile);
formData.append("title", title );
//and add more
```

or

```
let title = document.getElementById("title").value;
let firstFile= document.getElementById("list-photos[]").files[0];  // file from input
let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append("file1", firstFile);
formData.append("title", title );
                           
req.open("POST", '/upload/image');
req.send(formData);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. How should I send the input fields?

Comment: just add them to the formData like the file

Comment: Going to try your solution. after I'm finished refactoring my code :)